# Objects memory management in Java on Android

Tags: java, android, memory-management

If I have :

- An object A containing a `List<B>`
- All objects B in my `List<B>` containing a `List<C>`
- all objects C in my `List<C>` containing a `List<D>`
  etc...

How the memory is managed ? all "linked" objects (B,C,D...) are instanciated and put in memory when the object A is instanciated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `new()` the memory required for the corresponding object is taken from the heap.

As you most often **start** by creating an empty list - only the memory required for that thing is requested.

In other words: there is no way to create the "complete" structure in one shot. It makes no difference if you do:

```
List<List<String>> strings = new ArrayList<>();
```

or

```
List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
```

The amount of memory that is allocated on the heap is the *same* for both of these instructions! Because in *both* cases **one** new object is created (that ArrayList instance).

Comment: And just for the record: of course it is possible that doing `new A()` causes the creation of other objects (like when A has some fields, and the constructor of A creates new objects itself).

Comment: Actually i was just asking myself this question while using an ORM with several tables containing relationships even some circular ones. I thought it could quickly turns to a big memory load but I guess that in this specific case it depends how the ORM is implemented...

Comment: Correct. There are actually *many* different aspects that come into play here. There can't be a generic answer on that level - so it is good that you were able to somehow turn this into an "ok" question ;-)

Comment: Actually when I asked the question i was focused on my ORM problem and just tried to generalize the question... i just didn't realize that when I generalized it it became a kind of Java programming basic question until I got these down votes and saw your answer... but actually it's not so evident if you look deeper... and not easy to find this question on stack overflow so.. can be useful here :) again thank you for your time.

Comment: As said: to understand what some ORM tool is doing - you need to know A) what tool B) what data C) what kind of "interactions"

Answer (score 0):

The statement `List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();` only allocates heap space for the list itsself, the list only stores **references** to the object it contains, it doesn't contain the objects themselves.

Note that an ArrayList is using an array as it's internal structure (you might have guessed that), so the constructor is basically allocating an array of an initial size. For creating huge ArrayLists, you should pre-allocate space to be more efficient, e.g. `List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(2000);` preallocates space for 2000 String references.